# Emacs does not navigate to the error from compile-mode

Tags: debugging, error-handling, emacs

If I use the compile-mode to run `yarn test` I get an stacktrace like this:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/code/MyProject" -*-
Compilation started at Tue Apr 24 09:54:23

yarn test
yarn run v1.6.0
$ jest 'src'
 FAIL  src/scenes/MainScene.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ~/code/MyProject/node_modules/phaser/src/renderer/webgl/shaders/BitmapMask.frag:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){#define SHADER_NAME PHASER_BITMAP_MASK_FS
                                                                                             ^

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/phaser/src/renderer/webgl/pipelines/BitmapMaskPipeline.js:9:22)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.866s
Ran all test suites matching /src/i.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Tue Apr 24 09:54:26
```

Emacs autommatically detects the errors which is cool! So I press `<TAB>` it moves the cursor to the line:

```
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316:17)
```

Then, I press `<CR>` to try to navigate to the file, but instead I get helm asking me at the bottom of the screen:

```
Find this error in (default node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:316): ~/code/MyProject
```

For some reason it seems that it can't find the path to the file, I'm wondering if it is because the stacktrace has the line number appended to it. Is there a way to configure the `compile-goto-error` function to take this into account?

Comment: and jenesaisquoi came to save the day! :) Thank you mate, do you mind to add an answer so I can accept it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add entries to the `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` to match error output in the compilation buffer. There are a lot of options you can read about in the docs for matching errors. For your example,

```
(push 'my-error-1 compilation-error-regexp-alist)
(push '(my-error-1
        "^[ ]*at .* (\\([^:]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\))" 1 2)
      compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)
```

The first capture group specifies the file, the second the line number, the third would be the column if needed to use that as well.